# New chapter command for attachment

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I am searching a solution to change the definition of the chapter command before putting the attachment in my document, which is a scrreprt.

With the scrreprt class, my normal chapters have only a number and then the title.
My goal would be to let that as it is for the normal chapters, then, when I begin the attachment part, that my chapters have an other layout: simply the words "attachment" before the numbering, like "Attachment 1. Title of this attachment".

It should have the same behaviour in the table of contents: normal chapters should just be numeroted as usual and then the ones in the attachment part should have the word attachment before.

I already tried some things, I think it should be possible with a \renewcommand at the begin of the attachment part, or maybe a \newcommand named for instance \attachment based on the \chapter command, but I don't understand how it works.

Could someone please help me?

If I write a minimal exemple I have something like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}
\chapter{Title of chapter 1}
\chapter{Title of chapter 2}
\part{Attachment}
\chapter{Title of attachment 1}
\chapter{Title of attachment 2}
\end{document}
```

Thank you forward for your help, sorry for my bad english and have a nice day/evening/something ;-)

Comment: Why not using `\appendix` and its features, redefining `\appendixname` to contain `Attachment` instead of `Appendix`

Comment: You will find answers to your other questions in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163890/9632)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the great [answer of esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319109/5239) you can use the following code in your preamble:

```
\newcommand\tocappendixnumber[1]{\chapapp~#1}
\newcommand\startattachment{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
   \RedeclareSectionCommand[
      tocdynnumwidth,
      tocentrynumberformat=\tocappendixnumber
    ]{chapter}}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot
      \IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}%
  }
}
```

After `\part{Attachment}` use `\startattachment`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was really helpful, it took some time for me to answer because I had to update my whole library (I think an old package, probably the kom-script, crashed with your formule), and had some trouble doing this (had some right problem on the computer), but I finally did it ;-)
There is just one problem: your formule work fine, but instead of writing "attachment" before the number after the /startattachment, it writes "chapter". Any idea how to fix it? Except that all work fine, before the start attachment I have no text before the number, so thank you :)

Comment: Maybe I should precise that: I use my document in a german mode (ngerman, babel), so instead of "chapter" it is written "kapitel", I don't think it changes anything, but in doubt...