# KOMA-book numbering of appendix chapters

Tags: numbering, koma-script, appendix

I need to  number my appendix chapters with letters and show the word "appendix" before the letter both at the beginning of each appendix chapter and in the TOC. Also I need the appendix  letter formatted as the chapter numbers

I have been trying several solution both from the KOMA-script manual and from the forum, but nothing works.

I put the appendixprefix=true switch in the \documentclass (as indicated in the manual) but it does not change anything.

I have also tried the solutions suggested here:

[Prepend 'Appendix' before 'A' using scrbook](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163890/prepend-appendix-before-a-using-scrbook)

both with and without the appendixprefix=true but they do not work in my case.

Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass[chapterprefix=true,appendixprefix=true]{scrbook}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
    \usepackage{xcolor, graphicx}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{times}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
    
    
    \definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}
    
    \let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
    \addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
    %\setkomafont{element}{commands}
    \setkomafont{title}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
    \setkomafont{chapter}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
    \setkomafont{subtitle}{\color{black}}
    
    \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
        \scalebox{3}{\color{cyan}\thechapter}%
    }
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \author{}
    
    \subject{Linea Guida}
    \title{\textbf{Il trattamento laparoscopico di laparocele e ernie ventrali}}
    \subtitle{}
    \titlehead{}
    
    
    \date{Gennaio 2022}
    
    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Intro}
    
    
    
    \mainmatter
    \part{Sviluppo della linea guida}
    \chapter{one}
    \chapter{two}
    \part{Quesiti}
    \chapter{three}
    \chapter{four}
    \backmatter
    % bibliography, glossary and index would go here.
\appendix
\chapter{AppendixA}
\chapter{AppendixB}
    
    \end{document}
```

With:

```
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
    {\chapapp\nobreakspace\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
```

I was able to have the word "appendix" shown in the TOC (without any space between it and the title, BTW) but not at the beginning of the chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove `\backmatter`. The command is similar to `\frontmatter` regarding the headings: no numbers!

So it's just `\appendix`.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: Actually, I had just figured out by myself. Now it works after having inserted 

    \makeatletter
    \g@addto@macro\appendix{%
     \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
      {\chapapp\nobreakspace\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
     }
    
    }
    \makeatother for adding the word "appendix" in the chapter title. Why the letter in the appendix is smaller than the numbers in the chapters?

Comment: @FabioCampanile If the letter in appendix should have the same size as the chapter numbers you have to replace `\thechapter` by `\scalebox{3}{\thechapter}`.

Answer (score 0):

The following suggestion adds the prefix to the appendix chapters in document and in TOC:

```latex
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\chapternumdepth}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{title}{\color{cyan}}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\color{black}}
\addtokomafont{partnumber}{\color{cyan}}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\scalebox{3}{\thechapter}}

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/after}{%
  \AddToHook{cmd/chapterformat/before}{\chapapp\nobreakspace}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\appendixtocentry}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\appendixtocentry}{}{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    entrynumberformat=\tocappendixnumber,
    dynnumwidth
  ]{tocline}{chapter}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\tocappendixnumber}{m}{%
  \appendixname~#1%
}


\begin{document}
\author{}
\subject{Linea Guida}
\title{\textbf{Il trattamento laparoscopico di laparocele e ernie ventrali}}
\date{Gennaio 2022}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Intro}
\mainmatter
\part{Sviluppo della linea guida}
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\part{Quesiti}
\chapter{three}
\chapter{four}
%\backmatter% <- remove this!
% bibliography, glossary and index would go here.
\appendix
\chapter{AppendixA}
\chapter{AppendixB}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]